# Detect the parent controller variable change within the directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using a directive within a controller. There is a variable defined to an input field in the controller which will be updated when the user is typing.

This variable is also parsed to the directive as well. But the directive will be called once. What is the optimal way of updating the variable within the directive when it is changed in the controller ?

Comment: You could use a watcher that updated an internal variable of your directive

Answer (score 1):

Within your directive set `scope:false`

[Angularjs Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object)

> (default): No scope will be created for the directive. The directive will use its parent's scope.

Or Within your directive set `scope:true`, be sure you understand how js inheritance as you can end up masking properties

> true: A new child scope that prototypically inherits from its parent will be created for the directive's element. If multiple directives on the same element request a new scope, only one new scope is created.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Angular(if we are talking about 1.x version) always do `two-way` binding. So if you have the following bindings in the directive, the changes of the scope's property will always be propagated to directive:
    //inside directive declaration
    scope:{
       myVar:'=' // equals to '=myVar'.
    }

And consider the following usage of the directive:

```
<input ng-model="controllerScopeVar"/>
<my-directive myVar="controllerScopeVar"></my-directive>
```

In case of such usage the directive's internal `myVar` should be updated everytime the `controllerScopeVar` changes.

Another option for you is to shared scope in the directive, in this case the directive will inherit the scope of the parent controller. To se shared `scope` just remove `scope:{}` from directive's declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the parent controller variable change within the directive by using **$watch** on the model

Let the directive be like

```
app.directive('demoDir', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (newVal,oldVal) {
                console.log("New value:"+newVal +" and Old was :"+oldVal);
            });

        }
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data" demo-dir>
  </body>
```

Demo Plunker [Click here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ol36dEUQgKoUA7oaUmtZ?p=preview)